# Why the average doesn't work on power bi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to measure Patients per doctor via this measure formel
`Patients per Doctor = AVERAGE(DateDIM[Date].[Month], [Total Patients] )/ AVERAGE(DateDIM[Date].[Month], [# unik employe id])`

But it gives me an error meassage as "Too many arguments were passed to the AVERAGE function. The maximum argument count for the function is 1."

What's wrong how to fix it?

Comment: add some sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the error message says it clearly that AVERAGE() will take only one column name as parameter. Refer [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/average-function-dax)

Comment: Show us some sample data and the expected result out of it.